# Existence of a continuous surjection.

Tags: general-topology

I can find a continuous surjection from $\text{GL}(2,\mathbb R)$ to $\left\{\left(x,\frac 1x\right)\big|x\neq 0,x \in \mathbb R\right\}$,i.e. $\left(\det A,\frac{1}{\det A}\right)$. What about the existence of a continuous surjection to its complement in $\mathbb R^2$? My guess is that such a function will not exist but I cannot think of any conclusive argument.

Comment: Just to be clear, you’re asking for a surjection $GL_2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{(x,y),\, xy=1\}$? If so, note that the range has three connected components while the domain only has two.

Comment: Does a continuous surjection always preserve the number of connected components?

Comment: Not necessarily. But $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ has two connected components, so its continuous image is the reunion of two connected subspaces – so it can’t have three connected components. However, there is a surjective map $GL_2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and the range is connected.